# TurboGears2: gearbox --reload function not working

Tags: turbogears2

I've been working on a TG2 application for a while now, and whenever I use gearbox --serve --reload --debug, it works perfectly fine (read: whenever I make an edit in one of the python scripts I have, the application automatically restarts itself to show the edits and the errors). For some reason, that no longer works.

I've checked the forum, and I only saw one thread wherein this was addressed. One suggestion was to remove the .pyc files created by Python, but that doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
DM

**UPDATE:**

I tried making some edits before I launched the application (using gearbox serve --reload --debug), and I saw the revisions I made. And then, I tried editing a python script, and app didn't update.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried doing the following to check if the gearbox command would return to normal:

1) Restarted apache2
2) Updated virtualenv
3) Rebooted the amazon ec2 instance I'm working in
4) Re-installed tg.devtools

None of them worked. And now, even if I manually restart the application, the changes I've made doesn't appear on the site. I am not sure what's causing that bug in the gearbox command.

Answer (score 1):

What does apache2 have to do with gearbox?

`gearbox serve` acts as an alternative to using apache, so might it be that you are running your webapp under apache and expect gearbox to somehow reload apache?

In such case it won't work as `gearbox serve` would run another instance of the application which has nothing to do with the one running under apache.